# what's the meaning of 'ordercategoryname' in mimiciii

Tags: mimic-iii

I'm collecting informations of input data from mimiciii. I Find several strange data from the table.
[image]

In general, it is impossible to give patients 3000ml of liquid. I can also find similar records. One common character is that their ordercategoryname is '16-Pre Admission'. Should I exclude these data when I decide to calculate the daily input? what's the meaning of '16-Pre Admission'

Answer (score 0):

Pre-admission is as it sounds; before ICU admission. Often data here is used to document the amount of fluid received in the emergency department, operating room, etc. It's documented here as it's convenient for the care staff. For daily balance, it seems sensible to exclude pre-admission inputs, particularly as pre-admission fluid loss is rarely documented (e.g. you may know the patient received 5 units of blood in OR, but you don't have any documentation about how much they lost).